# Change Kubernetes pods logging

Tags: azure, debugging, logging, kubernetes

I Have an AKS (Azure Container Service) configured, up and running, with kubernetes installed.

Deploying containers on using [kubectl proxy] and the GUI of Kubernetes provided.

I am trying to increase the log level of the pods in order to get more information for better debugging.

I read a lot about `kubectl config set`

and the log level `--v=0` [0-10]

but not being able to change the log level. it seems the documentation

can someone point me out in the right direction?

Comment: which pods you mean?

Comment: @fiunchinho the pods created by each deployment. for example, a deployment creates a replica set and therefore a pod is created and related to this replica set. each pod created has logs, I want to increase the logging level to verbose in order to debug better.  thanks.

Comment: But that's app to every application to decide. Normally you'd configure this by passing environment variables to your application, and then the application would set the log level depending on this variable. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

The `--v` flag is an argument to `kubectl` and specifies the verbosity of the `kubectl` output. It has nothing to do with the log levels of the *application* running inside your Pods.

To get the logs from your Pods, you can run `kubectl logs <pod>`, or read `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/` on the Kubernetes node.

To increase the log level of your application, your application has to support it. And like @Jose Armesto said above, this is usually configured using an environment variable.